# What is the function call to update a form during an event

Tags: vb6

I am updating one of my old vb6 programs. I have not touched vb6 for a number of years.

I cannot recall if there was a property on the form or a method call which would update form controls during an event.

The best way to articulate this was something like this.

In pseudo and while trying to  avoid typing c# :)

```
button_click()
dim x as int = 0
while (x < 10000000)
   txtNumber.Text = x.ToString
   x = x + 1
end while
```

Currently, the txtNumber value does not update until the loop above has finished. Is there a form property or a method i must call to actual see the number increment?

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want a [`DoEvents`](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/118468) statement which will yield to the forms message queue.
(Can't find the VB6 link so the posted one is for VBA but its information is correct) or you can call `txtNumber.refresh`

Comment: Using the Refresh method on the control is generally preferable.  DoEvents() has many side effects you may not intend.